# Using OBS studio on Sway with Pipewire

Tags: wayland, pipewire, obs-studio, wireplumber

I am on Debian 12 / SWAY desktop which is WLR based.

---

I first install the *"OBS Studio"* version `29.0` with:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> sudo apt install obs-studio
```

*"OBS Studio"* can now be started with terminal command:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> obs
```

If *"OBS Studio"* is configured to run on *"Xorg"* by default we will not see our display! If this is the case we can still force it to run on *"Wayland"* like this:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> env QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland obs
```

Now it is surely using *"Wayland"* but this is still not enough for it to detect the desktop! I tried installing packages:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/0
  └─> sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-wlr
```

> **Attention:**
> *"Sway"* is based on *"WLR"* and therefore we installed `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr` *"portal"* implementation for `xdg-desktop-portal`. Different *"portal"* implementations exist and should be installed for different desktops. Debian supports *"portals"* for *"KDE"* (`xdg-desktop-portal-kde`), *"GTK"* (`xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`) or *"Gnome"* (`xdg-desktop-portal-gnome`).

I tested and made a conclusion that it does not matter which *"Pipewire session manager"* is used. By default people use `pipewire-media-session` but I use `wireplumber` which deprecates `pipewire-media-session` ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Session_manager)).

At this point I get no screens shown in *"OBS Studio"*! But I am able to record my screen and microphone using a simple CLI video recorder like this:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/0
  └─> sudo apt install wl-recorder
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/0
  └─> pw-jack wf-recorder -a
```

And this works like a charm...

It is just *"OBS Studio"* that fails to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all the *"portals"* we only have to install `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr`:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-wlr
```

> **Note:**
> *"Portal"* `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` is very large and will also install an entire Gnome desktop! So do not install this one unkless you use Gnome. In this case it will not make a difference for you.

This will also install a *"portal"* configuration file in `/usrl/share/xdg-desktop/portal/portals/wlr.portal`. Inside there is a list variable `UseIn`which contains `sway` and instructs `xdg-desktop-portal` to use this *"portal"* if it detects environmental variables `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway`, `XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=sway`.

And then we have to export enviromental desktop variables by putting this line in the Sway configuration file `~/.config/sway/config`:

```
exec dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd WAYLAND_DISPLAY DISPLAY SWAYSOCK XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=sway
```

> **Attention:**
> These enviromental variables will not work if they are only exported using the `/etc/environment`. If we want to do it like this, then we also have to import them in Sway by using this line of code in the
> `~/.config/sway/config`:
>
> ```
> exec systemctl --user import-environment"
> ```